# Can I use react with @spartacus framework?

Tags: reactjs, spartacus-storefront

My question is, can I use the react framework with @spartacus storefront? this is because our frontend application is developed in React and we want to use @Spartacus storefront to leverage advantages like decoupling front-end and Hybris build ..etc. but as it is developed on angular I am not sure whether it supports other frameworks like React within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spartacus needs Angular. So, I would say "NO", unless you want the complexity of integrating Angular with React.

Comment: Hi Geffchang, thank you and appreciate for your quick answer. do you have any idea of creating our own custom storefront with the desired framework and roughly how long would it take??

Comment: @ChiruP I'm sorry, I've no idea. However, you can create a frontend which doesn't use Spartacus. Just remember that you only need to communicate with Hybris' OCC / web services.

Answer (score 9):

There is some effort in making possible using web components as cms components, so you could use any technology to author them (including React), but it's still in the experimental phase (but works already).

More info is available in the docs:
https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/customizing-cms-components/#using-web-components-as-cms-components-experimental-support

And here you can find some example POCs for React, Vue, and Svelte:

- https://github.com/dunqan/react-cms-web-component
- https://github.com/dunqan/vue-cms-web-component
- https://github.com/dunqan/svelte-cms-web-component